# Google Scripts: Match Range and Update corresponding Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sheet1: DashBoard | Range: A7:B17

*(B7: Has a Filter Function that displays results of all Open Tasks from BackEnd Sheet)*

Sheet2: BackEnd   | Range: J56:M

**Match** B7:B17 with M56:M

if there is a match then

**Paste** values from A7:A17 to J56:J

[Click here for Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I19Z37YvQsV3lOz2DZStW1bA9F8YrNfJu-MQVj-fMmo/edit#gid=0)

The below script does the above operation but ONLY on the first instance of running it. Trying to repeat the process does not do anything. No errors on the code.

I'm a beginner to any form of coding and the below code was scripted by referring to various solutions on the forum. I might be missing some logic here and not in a position to de-code it in order to achieve the desired end result.

Thanks in advance

```
function updateToDo2() {
  var sh, toDo, status, update, i;
  sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('DashBoard')
  toDo = sh.getRange('B7:B17').getValues();
  status = sh.getRange('A7:A17').getValues();

  update = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('BackEnd').getRange('J56:M');

  update.setValues(update.getValues()
    .map(function(r, i) {
        if (r[3] == toDo[i]) {
            r[0] = status[i];
        }
        return r;
    })
  )
}
```

**EDIT:** Working Code but very slow. **Needs optimization**.
Please help!

```
function rowOfStatus(status) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('BackEnd');
  var data = sheet.getRange('M56:M60').getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == status) { //[1] because column B
      return i + 1;
    }
  }
}

function updateToDo() {
  var sh, sh1, dashboard, results, noteText, status, i, counter;
  sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('DashBoard');
  sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('BackEnd');
  dashboard = sh.getRange('A7:B11');
  results = dashboard.getDisplayValues();
  results.forEach(function(row) {
    status = row[0];
    noteText = row[1];
    counter = Number(rowOfStatus(noteText));
    if (counter > 0 && status != '') {
      counter = 55 + Number(rowOfStatus(noteText));
      sh1.getRange('J' + counter).setValue(status);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: `status` and `toDo` are both an array of arrays. Thus `status[i]` and `toDo[i]` are each an array, not a single value. Does fixing this resolve your issue?

Comment: Hi,
Well, I could not follow you there. I'm sorry. But I managed to put together a code with some in-house non-expert help and got the code working. The issue with the working code is it's very slow. I don't see how I can speed it up. Any help to optimize it will be great. I'll post the working Code in my question. Thanks!

Comment: Of course that runs horrendously slow, look at what you make it do: for every single row, you access the spreadsheet and read its entire data range **twice**. The best solution will operate read the sheet once, into a Javascript array, then at the end will write the new array, after making the appropriate modifications.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your observation. Like I mentioned in my post, I'm a novice to coding and all I could manage was a solution that is not optimized and I don't have the expertise to correct that. I could not find a way to just read the range defined and put them in an array. Do you think you could help me in correcting the code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help in optimizing this code from Google Docs Help Forum and was provided by Jean-Pierre. Since I first posted my query on that Forum and was advised to post my query on StackOverflow by it's community member. Hence, here is the solution just in case it helps someone here. It's short & pretty fast!

[Google Forum Link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/BOIB0ccP9nk;context-place=starred)

**Code:**

```
function updateToDo() {
var ss, arr, values, colB, backendValues, backendColM;
ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
arr = [];
values = ss.getSheetByName('DashBoard').getRange('A7:B17').getValues()
colB = values.map(function (v) {
    return v[1];
})
backendValues = ss.getSheetByName('BackEnd').getRange('J56:M').getValues()
backendColM= backendValues.map(function (bv) {return bv[3]}).forEach(function (el, i) {
    arr[i] = (el && colB.indexOf(el) > -1) ? ['Closed', 'Cancelled'].indexOf(values[colB.indexOf(el)][0]) > -1 ? [values[colB.indexOf(el)][0]] : [backendValues[i][0]]
    : [backendValues[i][0]];
})
ss.getSheetByName('BackEnd').getRange(56, 10, arr.length, 1).setValues(arr)
ss.getSheetByName('DashBoard').getRange('A7:A17').setValue(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely understanding what your doing but I thought I'd take a stab and trying to help you.  So this might not be what you want. In that case sorry to bother you.

```
function updateToDo2() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('DashBoard')
  var toDo=sh.getRange('B7:B17').getValues();
  var status=sh.getRange('A7:A17').getValues();
  var update=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('BackEnd').getRange('J56:M'+SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('BackEnd').getLastRow());
  var vA=update.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(vA[i][3]==toDo[i]){
      vA[i][0]=status[i];
    }
  }
  update.setValues(vA);
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper,
Your script updates the status of To-Do items from the DashBoard to the BackEnd as required. 
But, trying to update few more items, the script does not do what it did the first time. Let me know if you got what I plan to do. Thanks for helping me out.